# Is there another difference between sleep and usleep?

Tags: php, sleep, usleep

Is the only difference between sleep function and usleep one Is that the parameter of first one is in seconds and the other one in micro seconds ?? Is there any difference else ??

Anther thing please, I'll use this functions with loops, Is there any problem will accident me on that??

Answer (score 6):

From a review of the PHP documentation on [`usleep`](http://php.net/usleep) and that of [`sleep`](http://php.net/sleep), you'll notice that there are **2 differences**:

1. The argument for `usleep` is an integer representing micro seconds (a micro second is one millionth of a second), while the argument for `sleep` is an integer representing seconds.
2. `sleep` returns "zero on success, or FALSE on error."  `usleep` has **no return value**.  Here are more details on the return value for `sleep`:

> If the call was interrupted by a signal, sleep() returns a non-zero
>   value. On Windows, this value will always be 192 (the value of the
>   WAIT_IO_COMPLETION constant within the Windows API). On other
>   platforms, the return value will be the number of seconds left to
>   sleep.

In general, you should be ok using these functions within loops.  That being said, though, the more important questions to ask are: *Why do you need a solution that depends on halting execution for a certain amount of time?  Is this really a good solution to your problem, or is it a hack-fix for some strange bug or edge case that you just want to have go away?*

Answer (score -1):

`usleep` — Delay execution in microseconds.
Halt time in micro seconds. A micro second is one millionth of a second.

```
`sleep` — Delay execution

Delays the program execution for the given number of seconds.
```

i don't get more difference  between this two function

Answer (score -2):

sleep() allows your code to sleep in seconds.

```
sleep(5); // sleeps for 5 seconds
```

usleep() allows your code with respect to microseconds.

```
usleep(2500000); // slees for 2.5 seconds
```

Other than that, I think they're identical.

```
sleep($n) == usleep($n * 1000000)
usleep(25000) only sleeps for 0.025 seconds.
```